# Oozie fails to create a MySQL database via Cloudera Manager: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, cloudera, oozie

This has me completely stumped.  I'm using Cloudera Manager on an Amazon EC2 Ubuntu instance to start up Oozie w/ MySQL.  I tried reading all of the other questions regarding jdbc and MySQL and have tried a number of things for the past two days to try to get this set up, but it still fails. Every. Time.

I've tried adding mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar to just about every /lib/ folder there is for oozie and java.  It's in the following places:

```
/home/oozie_lib/oozie-workflows/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar
/usr/lib/hive/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar
/usr/lib/oozie/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar
/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar
```

However, when I attempt to create a new database in oozie using Cloudera Manager, I run into the following:

```
Error: Could not connect to the database: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Stack trace for the error was (for debug purposes):
--------------------------------------
java.lang.Exception: Could not connect to the database: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.validateConnection(OozieDBCLI.java:473)
    at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.createDB(OozieDBCLI.java:179)
    at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.run(OozieDBCLI.java:118)
    at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.main(OozieDBCLI.java:64)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.createConnection(OozieDBCLI.java:462)
    at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI.validateConnection(OozieDBCLI.java:469)
    ... 3 more
--------------------------------------
```

This is my /etc/environment:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre"
CLASSPATH="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib:."
```

Any tips/pointers on where to go from here?

Comment: have u found the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is too late as per the OQ.For future users,

I had a similar problem (Exception at `VALIDATE DB` step) and my mistake was appending a space in the **oozie.service.JPAService.jdbc.driver** property in **/etc/oozie/conf/oozie-site.xml**

```
    <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver </value>
```

Corrected as,

```
    <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
```